# Showing first element of the array

Tags: arrays, cakephp, search

How can I find and show Name of first element in a table?

I'm guessing that I have to use something like

```
$this->data['lastInvioce'] = $this->Invoice->find('all', array('limit' => 1));
```

... in controller to find it...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct. The first parameter of `Model::find()` indicates how many records to retrieve. `Model::find('all')` retrieves all matching records. What you want is `Model::find('first')`:

```
// Retrieve most recent Invoice record
$lastInvoice = $this->Invoice->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array( 'Invoice.name' ),
    'order' => array( 'Invoice.created' => 'desc' )
);
// Make this Invoice record available in the view
$this->set( compact('lastInvoice'));
```

This will retrieve the most recently created `Invoice` record, and only the `name` field. The `$this->set()` call makes the data in `$lastInvoice` available to your view. So:

```
echo $lastInvoice['Invoice']['name'];
```

Or alternatively:

```
extract($lastInvoice);
echo $Invoice['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$this->Invoice->find( 'first', ... )`. You can use other conditions and/or sorting to manipulate which record is the first, of course.